# Conditional sorting in Elastic search

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I am working on the sorting of es.
I have two columns "Score" and "Range". So I want to sort the records like first I will get all records with Score 0 then sorted by Range. I am not able to find any documentation of it on ES.
Like I have records
A with Score 0 and Range 7
B with Score 1 and Range 2
C with Score 0 and Range 7
D with Score 2 and Range 1

So I want results like A, C, D, B
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest using [script-based sorting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-body.html#_script_based_sorting). The idea of the script is to first return documents with `Score = 0` and if `Score > 0` the script use the `Range` value for sorting:

```
GET index/_search
{
    "sort" : {
        "_script" : {
            "type" : "number",
            "script" : {
                "lang": "painless",
                "source": "doc['Score'].value == 0 ? 0 : doc['Range'].value"
            },
            "order" : "asc"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I want all records that have score 0 first and then sorted by range.

Comment: Can you provide an example with a few sample documents?